# Java Swing revalidate() vs repaint()

Tags: java, swing

I'm putting together a Swing application where I often want to replace the contents of a JPanel. To do this, I'm calling `removeAll()`, then adding my new content, then calling `revalidate()`.

However I'm finding that the old content is still actually visible (though obscured by the the new content). If I add a call to `repaint()` in addition to `revalidate()`, it works as expected.

I'm sure on other occasions I've experienced that just calling `revalidate()` is enough.

So basically my question is - should I need to call both functions and if not, when should I call each of them?

Comment: [This tutorial from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html#custompaintingapi) states: "Always invoke repaint after revalidate". No explanation is provided though.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You need to call `repaint()` and `revalidate()`. The first one tells Swing that an area of the window is dirty (which is necessary to erase the image of the old children removed by `removeAll()`); the second one tells the layout manager to recalculate the layout (which is necessary when adding components). This should cause *children* of the panel to repaint, but may not cause the panel itself to do so (see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#triggers) for the list of repaint triggers).

On a more general note: rather than reusing the original panel, I'd recommend building a new panel and swapping them at the parent.

Comment: Could you rationalize why building a new panel is a better solution than using the old one? :)

Comment: @Arttu - it's less work, and therefore less prone to errors.

Answer (score 91):

Any time you do a remove() or a removeAll(), you should call

```
  validate();
  repaint();
```

after you have completed add()'ing the new components.

Calling validate() or revalidate() is mandatory when you do a remove() - see the relevant javadocs.

My own testing indicates that repaint() is also necessary. I'm not sure exactly why.

Answer (score 63):

`revalidate` is called on a container once new components are added or old ones removed.  this call is an instruction to tell the layout manager to reset based on the new component list.  `revalidate` will trigger a call to repaint what the component thinks are 'dirty regions.'  Obviously not all of the regions on your `JPanel` are considered dirty by the `RepaintManager`.

`repaint` is used to tell a component to repaint itself.  It is often the case that you need to call this in order to cleanup conditions such as yours.

Answer (score 7):

`revalidate()` just request to layout the container, when you experienced simply call `revalidate()` works, it could be caused by the updating of child components bounds triggers the `repaint()` when their bounds are changed during the re-layout. In the case you mentioned, only component removed and no component bounds are changed, this case no `repaint()` is **"accidentally"** triggered.

Answer (score -4):

yes you need to call 
    repaint();
    revalidate();
when you call removeAll() then you have to call repaint() and revalidate()