# JTable cell color changing after minimizing the main panel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I made a Setting panel, in which I am setting  color for Main table cell by pressing set button in setting window. There are two combo box button greater and less. The value  greater than the value in combo box will be colored in a particular color and less than in same way.  But the colors are not rendered after pressing <kbd>SET</kbd>, but it is rendered after minimizing and then maximizing the main window.

Below is actionPerformed() method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if(e.getSource()==btnCancel)
    {
      MainUI1.isShowModel=true;
    //mf.setVisible(true);
      this.dispose();
     }
   if(e.getSource()==btnset)
   {
      // MainUI1.isShowModel=true;
      ColorSettings.setColor();
      validate();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Component.repaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) method. Also see this question [Java Swing revalidate() vs repaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint)

Comment: I have tried it but color is set after minimizing or scrolling of main panel table only.

Comment: What component do you call `repaint` on?

Comment: @adityak everything are shots to the dark without seeing your code in the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) form, otherwise thats your issue and doesn't corresponding with code that you sent here somehow, basically set for Color doesn't required any woodoo as repaint or e.i. in the Swing

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov my job is done due to your suggestion. Thanx for your help.

Comment: @mKorbel THANX for your valuable suggetions