# How to call paint() in applets on an event

Tags: java, applet

Iam using applet for an application. In that when ever a conditin satifies,it has to call the paint method again. Is this possible with repaint method?? or any other methods to follow..??
I tried something like this,

```
if(j==0){
     ready_status=true;
     repaint();  // i want paint has to call again here      
  }
```

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint  PS: Did you try it yourself?  If not, why not?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).   (You have chosen a poor answer.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
paint(getGraphics());
```

Comment: `paint(getGraphics());`  This has a bad smell.  One should never call `paint(Graphics)`.  This is not a fix so much as a 'kludge' - likely to break on any other machine.

Comment: I agree - you should *not* be calling "paint()"!

Comment: You are right.Its not recommended.I should have said that.Just showed how he can call paint if he wants

Comment: *"Just showed how he can call paint if he wants"* Is 'he' programming only for 'his' eyes?  Generally not, so an approach that is 'likely to break on any other machine' is not something you should be including in an answer - for whatever reason.  If the OP asked how to shoot themselves in the foot, would you give them instructions?