# How to sort a string array within a GUI?

Tags: java, swing

I' having trouble with blue pelican lesson 19 project "two orders for the price of one". The code that is provided below is written within a GUI, my problem is that it only list the first name from the ascending/descending order when my string has multiple names that need to be printed.

```
String[] ss = {"Agnes",
               "Alfred",
               "Bernard",
               "Bill",
               "Ezra",
               "Herman",
               "Lee",
               "Mary",
               "Thomas"};
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++){
    jTextArea1.setText(ss[i]);
}
Arrays.sort(ss, Collections.reverseOrder());

for (String name: ss){
    jTextArea2.setText(name);
}
```

My GUI when ran:

[image]

Comment: You probably shouldn't be worrying about Java Swing while learning the basics. Your question really is how to have Swing display the sorted array.

Comment: what do you think `jTextArea2.setText(name);` does? (if in doubt, read the documentation)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's in response to me but in Swing there's other things going on that might be needed such as revalidate() - it doesn't always update automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865803/how-do-i-refresh-a-gui-in-java

Comment: Use a `JList`, you could even write a proxy `ListModel` which sorted another (unsorted `ListModel`)

Comment: @njzk2 it prints out a reversed ordered string in the second in the second text field (the text field on the right).

Comment: but what do you think `setText` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jTextArea1.setText(ss[i]);` is doing just that, it's "setting" the text to the value you are suppling, generally you either want to use `JTextArea#append` to append more text to the `JTextArea` or a `StringBuilder` to build a `String` within the loop, which you can apply in a single step through `setText`... however...

This is probably more complex then you were thinking, but your basic problem just screams `JList`.  See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.

Now, it would be very easy to simply create 3 `List`s of values, using the original, unsorted list, populate the other two and use `Collections.sort` to sort them, but where's the fun in that.

Instead, I use a custom `ListModel` which can sort another `ListModel` in the order you want.  The power of this is, the original is never changed, so it's order is preserved, but if you change either list (add/remove rows), they will both be updated

[image: Sorted]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataListener;

public class SortExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SortExample();
    }

    public SortExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JList unsorted;
        private JList ascending;
        private JList descending;

        public TestPane() {
            String[] ss = {"Agnes",
                "Alfred",
                "Bernard",
                "Bill",
                "Ezra",
                "Herman",
                "Lee",
                "Mary",
                "Thomas"};
            List<String> listOfValues = Arrays.asList(ss);
            Collections.shuffle(listOfValues);
            DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
            for (String value : listOfValues) {
                model.addElement(value);
            }

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(new JLabel("Unsorted"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JLabel("Ascending"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JLabel("Descending"), gbc);

            unsorted = new JList(model);
            ascending = new JList(new SortedListModel(model, SortedListModel.SortOrder.Ascending));
            descending = new JList(new SortedListModel(model, SortedListModel.SortOrder.Descending));

            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JScrollPane(unsorted), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JScrollPane(ascending), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JScrollPane(descending), gbc);
        }

    }

    /**
     * SortedListModel decorates an unsorted ListModel to provide a sorted
     * model. You can create a SortedListModel from models you already have.
     * Place the SortedListModel into a JList, for example, to provide a sorted
     * view of your underlying model.
     *
     * @author John O'Conner
     */
    public static class SortedListModel extends AbstractListModel {

        private ListDataHandler hndListData;
        private List<SortedListEntry> sortedModel;
        private ListModel unsortedModel;
        private Comparator comparator;
        private SortOrder sortOrder;

        public enum SortOrder {
            Unsorted,
            Ascending,
            Descending;
        }

        private SortedListModel() {
            setSortOrder(SortOrder.Unsorted);
            setComparator(Collator.getInstance());
        }

        /**
         * Create a SortedListModel from an existing model using a default text
         * comparator for the default Locale. Sort in ascending order.
         *
         * @param model the underlying, unsorted ListModel
         */
        public SortedListModel(ListModel model) {
            this(model, SortOrder.Ascending, null);
        }

        /**
         * Create a SortedListModel from an existing model using a specific
         * comparator and sort order. Use a default text comparator.
         *
         * @param model the unsorted list model
         * @param sortOrder that should be used
         */
        public SortedListModel(ListModel model, SortOrder sortOrder) {
            this(model, sortOrder, null);
        }

        /**
         * Create a SortedListModel from an existing model. Sort the model in
         * the specified sort order using the given comparator.
         *
         * @param model
         * @param sortOrder
         * @param comp
         *
         */
        public SortedListModel(ListModel model, SortOrder sortOrder, Comparator comp) {
            this();
            setComparator(comp);
            setModel(model);
            setSortOrder(sortOrder);
        }

        public void setModel(ListModel model) {
            if (unsortedModel == null || !unsortedModel.equals(model)) {
                if (unsortedModel != null) {
                    fireIntervalRemoved(this, 0, unsortedModel.getSize() - 1);
                    unsortedModel.removeListDataListener(getListDataHandler());
                }

                unsortedModel = model;
                if (unsortedModel != null) {
                    unsortedModel.addListDataListener(getListDataHandler());
                }

                // get base model info
                int size = model.getSize();

                List<SortedListEntry> sortedModel = getSortedModel();
                sortedModel.clear();
                for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x) {
                    SortedListEntry entry = new SortedListEntry(x);
                    int insertionPoint = findInsertionPoint(entry);
                    sortedModel.add(insertionPoint, entry);
                }
            }
        }

        protected ListDataHandler getListDataHandler() {
            if (hndListData == null) {
                hndListData = new ListDataHandler();
            }
            return hndListData;
        }

        public SortOrder getSortOrder() {
            return sortOrder;
        }

        protected List<SortedListEntry> getSortedModel() {
            if (sortedModel == null) {
                sortedModel = new ArrayList<SortedListEntry>(25);
            }
            return sortedModel;
        }

        public ListModel getModel() {
            return unsortedModel;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve the sorted entry from the original model
         *
         * @param index index of an entry in the sorted model
         * @return element in the original model to which our entry points
         */
        public Object getElementAt(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
            Object element = null;
            if (getModel() != null) {
                int modelIndex = toUnsortedModelIndex(index);
                element = getModel().getElementAt(modelIndex);
            }
            return element;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve the size of the underlying model
         *
         * @return size of the model
         */
        public int getSize() {
            int size = getSortedModel().size();
            return size;
        }

        /**
         * Convert sorted model index to an unsorted model index.
         *
         * @param index an index in the sorted model
         * @return modelIndex an index in the unsorted model
         *
         */
        public int toUnsortedModelIndex(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
            int modelIndex = -1;
            SortedListEntry entry = getSortedModel().get(index);
            modelIndex = entry.getIndex();
            return modelIndex;
        }

        /**
         * Convert an array of sorted model indices to their unsorted model
         * indices. Sort the resulting set of indices.
         *
         * @param sortedSelectedIndices indices of selected elements in the
         * sorted model or sorted view
         * @return unsortedSelectedIndices selected indices in the unsorted
         * model
         */
        public int[] toUnsortedModelIndices(int[] sortedSelectedIndices) {
            int[] unsortedSelectedIndices = new int[sortedSelectedIndices.length];
            int x = 0;
            for (int sortedIndex : sortedSelectedIndices) {
                unsortedSelectedIndices[x++] = toUnsortedModelIndex(sortedIndex);
            }

            // sort the array of indices before returning
            Arrays.sort(unsortedSelectedIndices);
            return unsortedSelectedIndices;
        }

        /**
         * Convert an unsorted model index to a sorted model index.
         *
         * @param unsortedIndex an element index in the unsorted model
         * @return sortedIndex an element index in the sorted model
         */
        public int toSortedModelIndex(int unsortedIndex) {
            int sortedIndex = -1;
            int x = -1;
            for (SortedListEntry entry : getSortedModel()) {
                ++x;
                if (entry.getIndex() == unsortedIndex) {
                    sortedIndex = x;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return sortedIndex;
        }

        /**
         * Convert an array of unsorted model selection indices to indices in
         * the sorted model. Sort the model indices from low to high to
         * duplicate JList's getSelectedIndices method
         *
         * @param unsortedModelIndices
         * @return an array of selected indices in the sorted model
         */
        public int[] toSortedModelIndices(int[] unsortedModelIndices) {
            int[] sortedModelIndices = new int[unsortedModelIndices.length];
            int x = 0;
            for (int unsortedIndex : unsortedModelIndices) {
                sortedModelIndices[x++] = toSortedModelIndex(unsortedIndex);
            }

            Arrays.sort(sortedModelIndices);
            return sortedModelIndices;
        }

        private void resetModelData() {
            int index = 0;
            for (SortedListEntry entry : getSortedModel()) {
                entry.setIndex(index++);
            }
        }

        public void setComparator(Comparator comp) {
            if (comparator == null || !comparator.equals(comp)) {
                comparator = comp;
                if (comparator == null) {
                    setSortOrder(SortOrder.Unsorted);
                    comparator = Collator.getInstance();

                    resetModelData();
                } else if (getModel() != null) {
                    Collections.sort(getSortedModel());
                }

                if (getModel() != null) {
                    fireContentsChanged(ListDataEvent.CONTENTS_CHANGED, 0, getSortedModel().size() - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change the sort order of the model at runtime
         *
         * @param value
         */
        public void setSortOrder(SortOrder value) {
            if (sortOrder != value) {
                sortOrder = value;
                if (value == SortOrder.Unsorted) {
                    resetModelData();
                } else if (getModel() != null) {
                    Collections.sort(getSortedModel());
                }

                if (getModel() != null) {
                    fireContentsChanged(ListDataEvent.CONTENTS_CHANGED, 0, getSortedModel().size() - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Update the sorted model whenever new items are added to the
         * original/decorated model.
         *
         */
        private void unsortedIntervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {
            int begin = e.getIndex0();
            int end = e.getIndex1();
            int nElementsAdded = end - begin + 1;

            /* Items in the decorated model have shifted in flight.
                 * Increment our model pointers into the decorated model.
                 * We must increment indices that intersect with the insertion
                 * point in the decorated model.
             */
            for (SortedListEntry entry : getSortedModel()) {
                int index = entry.getIndex();
                // if our model points to a model index >= to where
                // new model entries are added, we must bump up their index
                if (index >= begin) {
                    entry.setIndex(index + nElementsAdded);
                }
            }

            // now add the new items from the decorated model
            for (int x = begin; x <= end; ++x) {
                SortedListEntry newEntry = new SortedListEntry(x);
                int insertionPoint = findInsertionPoint(newEntry);

                getSortedModel().add(insertionPoint, newEntry);

                fireIntervalAdded(ListDataEvent.INTERVAL_ADDED, insertionPoint, insertionPoint);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Update this model when items are removed from the original/decorated
         * model. Also, let our listeners know that we've removed items.
         */
        private void unsortedIntervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {
            int begin = e.getIndex0();
            int end = e.getIndex1();
            int nElementsRemoved = end - begin + 1;

            /*
                 * Move from end to beginning of our sorted model, updating
                 * element indices into the decorated model or removing
                 * elements as necessary
             */
            int sortedSize = getSortedModel().size();
            boolean[] bElementRemoved = new boolean[sortedSize];

            for (int x = sortedSize - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
                SortedListEntry entry = getSortedModel().get(x);
                int index = entry.getIndex();
                if (index > end) {
                    entry.setIndex(index - nElementsRemoved);
                } else if (index >= begin) {
                    getSortedModel().remove(x);
                    bElementRemoved[x] = true;
                }
            }
            /*
                 * Let listeners know that we've removed items.
             */
            for (int x = bElementRemoved.length - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
                if (bElementRemoved[x]) {
                    fireIntervalRemoved(ListDataEvent.INTERVAL_REMOVED, x, x);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Resort the sorted model if there are changes in the original unsorted
         * model. Let any listeners know about changes. Since I don't track
         * specific changes, sort everywhere and redisplay all items.
         */
        private void unsortedContentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {
            Collections.sort(getSortedModel());
            fireContentsChanged(ListDataEvent.CONTENTS_CHANGED, 0, getSortedModel().size() - 1);
        }

        /**
         * Internal helper method to find the insertion point for a new entry in
         * the sorted model.
         */
        private int findInsertionPoint(SortedListEntry entry) {
            int insertionPoint = getSortedModel().size();
            if (getSortOrder() != SortOrder.Unsorted) {
                insertionPoint = Collections.binarySearch((List) getSortedModel(), entry);
                if (insertionPoint < 0) {
                    insertionPoint = -(insertionPoint + 1);
                }
            }
            return insertionPoint;
        }

        public Comparator getComparator() {
            return comparator;
        }

        public class SortedListEntry implements Comparable {

            private int index;

            private SortedListEntry() {
            }

            public SortedListEntry(int index) {
                this.index = index;
            }

            public int getIndex() {
                return index;
            }

            public void setIndex(int index) {
                this.index = index;
            }

            public int compareTo(Object o) {

                int comparison = 0;
                if (getModel() != null && getComparator() != null) {
                    // retrieve the element that this entry points to
                    // in the original model
                    Object thisElement = getModel().getElementAt(index);
                    SortedListEntry thatEntry = (SortedListEntry) o;
                    // retrieve the element that thatEntry points to in the original
                    // model
                    Object thatElement = getModel().getElementAt(thatEntry.getIndex());
                    if (getComparator() instanceof Collator) {
                        thisElement = thisElement.toString();
                        thatElement = thatElement.toString();
                    }
                    // compare the base model's elements using the provided comparator
                    comparison = getComparator().compare(thisElement, thatElement);
                    // convert to descending order as necessary
                    if (getSortOrder() == SortOrder.Descending) {
                        comparison = -comparison;
                    }
                }

                return comparison;
            }
        }

        protected class ListDataHandler implements ListDataListener {

            public void intervalAdded(ListDataEvent e) {
                unsortedIntervalAdded(e);
            }

            public void intervalRemoved(ListDataEvent e) {
                unsortedIntervalRemoved(e);
            }

            public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent e) {
                unsortedContentsChanged(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The concept of using a "proxy" model like this goes WAY back to Java 1.3, before we had things like `RowSorter`, which you might be able to use for this instead, but I've never had the time to go back an investigate it.

Using proxy models like this is a great way of adding new functionality to components, without the need to modify the existing code

Comment: is there real idea to using JList with Comparator (bunch of code lines thats already implemented in a few APIs, with some importantn optimalizations - performance), isn't JTable easiest

Comment: @mKorbel As I said, it's probably possible to use `RowSorter`, but I've not investigated that, as I have this available in my API libraries :P

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is that you are iterating but not taking all iteration into consideration

```
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++){
    // setText will replace current text with ss[i]
    // i = 0  jTextArea1 text = Agnes
    // i = 1  jTextArea1 text = Alfred and not Agnes + Alfred
    jTextArea1.setText(ss[i]);
}
Arrays.sort(ss, Collections.reverseOrder());

for (String name: ss){
    // same here name final value will be last value of name
    jTextArea2.setText(name);
}
```

so either create string and append to it and set `TextArea` value to final appended string

```
String myVal = ""
for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++){
   myVal += ss[i];
}
jTextArea1.setText(myVal);
```

Use [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) if you want to have select box like list