# Sort JList entries by creation date

Tags: java, swing, listener, jlist

I'm just about to implement my first Java project and now at a point where I do not really get further.

The program is relatively simple. There is the possibility to create notes, which are displayed in a JList. You can change the notes, delete them and as a new feature, there should be a button to sort the notes within the JList ascending / descending by creation date.

The requirement for the implementation of the function, however, is the following: "According to the MVC principle I should not change the order of the objects inside my model, but only the entries in the JList". And that confuses me a little bit. I would have ordered the internal database with a Comperator or Decorate Pattern and then display the result, but that's not required.
And now I am stuck. I always thought that the model is the basis for the view and that all the changes take place in the model.

As I said, I am a beginner and have searched even on Google and looked at several tutorials, but I lack the experience to know which approach is the right one and how to design the whole functionality. I think it has something to do with Listeners but I am not sure how to implement that.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"Thanks for your help!"* Thanks for your question! Oh.. BTW - what **is** the question? Is your question *"How to X?"*?  If so, add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36764921/edit).  If not, think of a specific question and do the same (edit).

Comment: *"Sort JList entries by creation date"* I'd use a (potentially single column) `JTable` for that, since it includes the [`RowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) functionality. See also this [filtered font list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28621618/418556) which is a working example of using the `RowSorter` as a filter for records. *"..my first Java project.."* Then you should probably avoid trying to create a desktop app. with a GUI. That's advanced stuff!

Comment: Back in the old days before we had a sort/filter API, we use to make proxy models which could sort/filter these types of things, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735325/how-to-sort-a-string-array-within-a-gui/34735734#34735734)

Comment: Basically, the model still does it job, but internally, it does the juggling of the indices to make it look sorted

Comment: @Andrew I don’t get how my question is unclear?! I want to know how I can sort the entries in a JList without sorting the actual objects in my ListModel. I know that there is a class called RowSorter but this only works for Tables. But the requirement for this project is to use a JList and NOT a JTable.

And what is wrong about picking a challenging task for your first coding project? I mean, the only way to extend my knowledge is by trying out new things and deal with stuff I don’t understand, so I get better.

Comment: *"And what is wrong about picking a challenging task for your first coding project?"* Congratulations! You have proven you're capable of asking a question. Notably that is the *first* question you've asked (as opposed to describing a requirement or explaining what you don't understand/know - which *aren't* questions). In answer to that question, I never said it was 'bad', just 'better to avoid' at this early stage of understanding Java (or programming?). A GUI'd app. is inherently more complicated than an app. that works from the command line. For starters a GUI has it's own thread model ..

Comment: .. and added to the complexity for a cross platform GUI'd app. is laying out the components in a way that is logical across environments, and resizes in the most sensible manner (e.g. locking some components to original size and giving extra width and height to others).

Comment: @Andrew English is not my native tongue so I can’t express myself as clear as I want but here is one last try:
I know how to sort the objects inside my ListModel and then populate the JList with the results. All the content and properties of the notes are stored inside a .properties file. After starting the application these .properties files are loaded inside an array, sorted based on the creation date using the Decorate Pattern and then added to my ListModel...

Comment: ..But the requirement for the “Sort Ascending/Descending Button” – function is NOT to sort the actual array inside my ListModel where the  Notes-Objects are stored, but instead just sort the View (JList entries) without touching the ListModel.
And my question is: How can I sort entries inside my JList without touching the actual Data (Objects stored inside my ListModel)
I hope I am clear enough now.