# jToggleButton isSelected and setBackground is not working as expected

Tags: java, jtogglebutton

I am trying to make it so that the button will change color whenever it is selected. I tried using an if statement to see if the button is selected, and if it is, it will set it to red. However it doesn't work.

```
if(jToggleButton1.isSelected()) {
                    jToggleButton1.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
```

If anyone can describe to me how to make me work that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rerender your button . Then only you can see this is red.

Comment: Can you explain to me how I can re-render a button? I am still trying to learn Java and I'm not quite sure as to how I can do that.

Comment: hopefully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865803/how-do-i-refresh-a-gui-in-java this helps