# What's the difference between setVisible(true), repaint() and validate()?

Tags: java, repaint

I create a little program that load a frame in which I added some panels.
When I click on some button it should show some panels and hide other.
I'm experiencing some difficult to do it, even because I don't really figure out the diference between `setVisible(true)`, `repaint()` and `validate()` (that some friends of mine suggested to me).

I hope you can make me to understand!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to revalidate()? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint

Comment: I didn't know revalidate(), anyway i tried to use it and it doesn't work. I have also have a look at your link, but it don't help me.

I have this method:

[link](http://pastebin.com/RM1LLd0v)

Everytime i call the method the "list" content is different but the JList shows always the same content.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully read the API for [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html). The usages are:

1. `setVisible` - it will hide or show your component altogether. If you set it as `false`, you won't see it at all.
2. `repaint()` - is called when the actual pixels need to be redrawn, this is done **automatically**. It's used, for example, when you move a window on top of your GUI and then move it away. The part that was covered needs to be redrawn.
3. `validate()` - you should call this when the layout of your GUI has changed and you need the manager to replace and redraw your GUI.

It's a bit more complicated than that, so again, carefully read the API.

Comment: I have this method:

[link](http://pastebin.com/RM1LLd0v)

Everytime i call the method the "list" content is different but the JList shows always the same content.

Comment: @smartmouse I don't see a method list in what you linked. If the content of a JList is not updated, then you're probably not updating the data model.

Comment: Yes, it is updated.
I solved removing with this.add(viewPanel) after viewPanel.setVisiblue(true).

Answer (score 0):

**setVisible(true)**: sets the component so that it's visible.

**repaint()**: calls the paint method on the component.

**revalidate()**: updates the component based on the root component