# Toggle visibility of a JComponent Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to toggle visibility of a `JTextField` with a checkbox. If the checkbox is selected I want the `JTextField` to be displayed and vice-versa. My program works fine until I add the line that initializes the `JTextField` to be invisible at the start. If I remove this the segment works fine! Can you help me?

```
final JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1 = new JCheckBox("New Folder");
        panel_3.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);

        final JTextField textField_3 = new JTextField();
        panel_3.add(textField_3);

        textField_3.setColumns(20);
        //textField_3.setVisible(false); if a comment it in.. it never becomes visible

        chckbxNewCheckBox_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if(chckbxNewCheckBox_1.isSelected()){
                    textField_3.setVisible(true);
                }
                else 
                    textField_3.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) For many (or one & 'none') components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 3) For a `JCheckBox`, use an `ActionListener` rather than a `MouseListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) instead of `MouseListener`

```
checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        textField_3.setVisible(checkBox.isSelected());
    }
});
```

---

--EDIT--

call `panel_3.revalidate();` after changing its visibility.

Comment: It doens't work either... If I change the setVisible with the setEditable it works.

Comment: both are different methods. Don't know what's wrong with your code because your code is not visible to us.

Comment: If it works with `setEditable()` then call this one also along with `setVisible()`.

Comment: I know it should work but it doesn't :P This is all the code that is related about.

Comment: For more info have a look at [Java Swing revalidate() vs repaint()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint)

Answer (score 1):

When an element is invisible during container initialization, it never gets its dimensions initialized. You can check it by calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the text area after you set it to visible. They're both zero. So follow @Braj edit and call `panel.revalidate()` after you change element visibility to let layout manager know that it's time to reposition/recalculate some elements and give them proper size.

Answer (score 0):

You will do better with `ItemListener`

```
chckbxNewCheckBox_1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED))
            textField_3.setVisible(false);
        else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED))
            textField_3.setVisible(true);
        textField_3.revalidate();
    }
});
```

Note: pelase follow naming conventions and use underscores only for constants.

Answer (score -1):

Consider calling `pack()` method

Below is the complete code I experimented with:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        final JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox_1 = new JCheckBox("New Folder");
        final JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel_3);

        panel_3.add(chckbxNewCheckBox_1);

        final JTextField textField_3 = new JTextField();
        panel_3.add(textField_3);

        textField_3.setColumns(20);
        textField_3.setVisible(false); //if a comment it in.. it never becomes visible

        chckbxNewCheckBox_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if (chckbxNewCheckBox_1.isSelected()) {
                    textField_3.setVisible(true);
                } else
                    textField_3.setVisible(false);

                frame.pack();
            }
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: `MouseAdapter` is not the way to go with a check box.

Comment: @user1803551 I just did enough to solve the askers problem. I didn't check his code for all possible errors. Thanks for downvoting.

Comment: `pack()` will also resize the frame to compensate for the change of space. This is not the right approach even if it works.