# JButton takes 2 clicks

Tags: java, swing

I have a main `JPanel` that's called `board` which has another `JPanel` in it with two `JButtons' one of which is supposed to remove this panel when clicked.

```
public class AditWindow extends JPanel {
    private int width;
    private int height;

public AditWindow(int x, int y){
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        width=180;
        height=60;
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        JButton addLoc = new JButton("Add Location");
        JButton addSign = new JButton("Add Sign");
        addLoc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                close();
                System.out.println("click");
            }
        });
        addSign.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("addSign");
            }
        });
        Main.font=Main.font.deriveFont(13f);
        addLoc.setFont(Main.font);
        addSign.setFont(Main.font);
        addLoc.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, 30));
        addSign.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, 30));
        addLoc.setBackground(new Color(0xF6F6F6));
        addSign.setBackground(new Color(0xF6F6F6));
        add(addLoc);
        add(addSign);
        Main.board.validate();

private void close(){
        System.out.println("close");
        Main.board.del(this);
        }
}
```

The del method is:

```
public void del(Component c){
        remove(c);
        validate();
        System.out.println("removed");
        }
```

Problem is: for some reason it takes 2 clicks for the panel to get removed, but the lines get printed on both clicks. I am unsure how to properly manage this situation.

EIDT: If I remove the validate() line from the del() method it will work from the first click but only the buttons will dissapear leaving a rectangle background of the JPanel on the screen.

Comment: So does both "close" and "click" get printed?

Comment: @Ageoffan Yes, on both clicks it prints:
close
removed
click

Comment: Can't say I ever had an issue like that, try maybe doing this.c in the close method?

Comment: @Ageoffan what is this.c? It can't resolve it.

Comment: Nvm, thought maybe the "this" command needs to be more specific.

Comment: @seMikel It is hard to tell what went wrong. You need to show us what is in class `Main`.

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

You might try invoking the remove/validate within a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() call.

Comment: So something like this:`public void del(final Component c){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                remove(c);
                validate();
                System.out.println("removed");
            }
        });

    }`
?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Could also be the problem that you are calling validate(). You might want revalidate() instead. Or even repaint().. Check this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint

Answer (score 0):

try passing AditWindow.this to the Main.board.del() method instead of this.

Comment: Still requires a second click