# Add Textfields on Jframe at Runtime

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I am trying to create text-fields on frame by getting input at run-time. Is it possible? Or I have to create another frame for that. I tried this code, but it's not working. Please Help me out, and tell me what's wrong with this code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Check extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JTextField txtqty;
JTextField[] tfArr;
JPanel p1,p2;
JButton bsmbt;

public Check()
{
    GUIDesign();
}

public void GUIDesign()
{
    p1 = new JPanel();
    txtqty = new JTextField(10);
    JButton bsmbt= new JButton("OK");
    p1.add(txtqty);
    p1.add(bsmbt);

    p2=new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(null);
    add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocation(100, 100);

    bsmbt.addActionListener(this);




}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Check();
}

public void TFArray(JTextField[] temp)
{
    int x,y,width,height;
    x=10;y=30;width=50;height=20;
    int no_of_textboxes = Integer.parseInt(txtqty.getText());
    temp=new JTextField[no_of_textboxes];

    for(int i=0;i<no_of_textboxes;i++)
    {
        temp[i]= new JTextField(10);
        temp[i].setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        x+=(width+10);
        p2.add(temp[i]);

    }
    add(p2);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, txtqty.getText());
        TFArray(tfArr);
}


}
```

->Method TFArray() isn't working.

Comment: What part isn't working? What is the result you are getting? How does it differ from what you want?

We need more visibility, friend!

Comment: This code is showing just one textfield with one button which I created above in panel1 in GUIDesign() method. I wanted to create as many textfields given at input. but This code doesn't works.

Comment: 1) `public void TFArray` method names should be lowerCamelCase, 2) `extends JFrame` don't extend `JFrame` instead if you need to extend something, extend from `JPanel` and create an instance of `JFrame`. 3) `JButton bsmbt= new JButton("OK");` You're aware that your global variable `JButton bsmbt;` isn't used because of that line right?. 4) What part exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Method TFArray() isn't working.

Comment: You need to call [`revalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) and [`repaint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(java.awt.Rectangle)), [See this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint) but please use a [Layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Thanks Bro, revalidate() did the trick, but it appears to be refreshing the GUI for one time only. Do you know why?
Suppose I run the project, and enter 2 in textfield and click on button.
The above code creates 2 textfields. but when I again put some value and submit it, it doesn't seem to reflect any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many errors in your code:

1. `public void TFArray(JTextField[] temp)`: method names should start with lowerCamelCase
2. You're extending `JFrame`, you shouldn't extend `JFrame`, because when you extend it your class **is a** `JFrame`, `JFrame` is rigid so you can't place it inside anything else, instead you might consider creating a `JFrame` instance and if you ever need to extend `JComponent` extend from `JPanel`.
3. `JButton bsmbt= new JButton("OK");` the variable `bsmbt` is a local variable inside your constructor, your global variable `bsmbt` is not used anywhere, and if you try to use it later you'll get a `NullPointerException`, instead change that line to:

   ```
   bsmbt= new JButton("OK");
   ```
4. You're using `null` layout for `p2`, instead use a proper [Layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and read [Null layout is evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing). Swing was designed to work with different PLAFs, screen sizes and resolutions, while pixel perfect GUIs (with `setBounds()`) might seem like the best and faster way to create a complex GUI in Swing, the more GUIs you make, the more errors you'll get due to this.

To solve your problem call [`revalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) and [`repaint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(java.awt.Rectangle))

> The above code creates 2 textfields. but when I again put some value and submit it, it doesn't seem to reflect any changes.

That might be because you're overriding `x`, `y`, `height` and `width` variables each time you enter `TFArray` method. But that is a guess, if you want a real answer, follow the suggestions above and post a proper and valid [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)