# Setting Focusable Window on JPanel from another JPanel by Frame's command class, doesn't working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I'm not sure if I explained well on the title. So here are the details.

*(Down below are my notes if they can help you)*

I'm trying to test my skills on Java by creating a Window that will add the Menu `JPanel` on it when the program starts, and when I call the command to Run the New `JPanel` Game and remove the `JPanel` Menu, I have to Minimize the window and get it back to top to see the new `JPanel` Game panel that I have created.

I have used `repaint();` method and `setFocusable(true);` or `setRequestFocusInWindow();` commands directly or from JPanel's or frame window as well like `panel.repaint();` etc., but that's not enough. What I'm missing?

I am not gonna be bored and show my entire code, I'll show the only the important lines.

So here I'm creating and calling my First `JPanel` Menu Window on `JFrame`.

```
public class Starting_Window {

    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Simple Game By Erick");
    public static GameFrameMenu menuG = new GameFrameMenu();
    public static PlayingClass game = new PlayingClass();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800/4*3);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(menuG);

    }

}
```

So once my code started I have set a contractor for GameFrameMenu so I can add the basics `JButtons` or anything like that on Menu Panel. So now with few words, this is what happens when the user presses the JButton I have created.

```
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                menuTimer.stop();
                Starting_Window.menuG.removeAll();
                Starting_Window.menuG.repaint();
                Starting_Window.frame.repaint();
                Starting_Window.frame.add(Starting_Window.game);
                Starting_Window.game.setFocusable(true);
                Starting_Window.game.repaint();
                Starting_Window.frame.remove(Starting_Window.menuG);

            }
        });
```

So after that this is my code on `PlayingClass`:

```
public class PlayingClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Timer gameTimer;

    public PlayingClass() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setLayout(null);

        gameTimer = new Timer(10,this);
        gameTimer.start();

    }

    int x = 50, y = 50;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        x++;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

}
```

***Notes:***

I use `paint(Graphics g)` method on JPanels.

Once I press the button, my screen get's white.

Once I minimize it and get back to it I see the new `JPanel` that I have added on.

The screen runs normally without bugs.

Comment: If the frame is already visible when you add the component, and you're using a layout manager (doesn't seem like you changed the default layout of the frame, which is `BorderLayout`), you need to call `revalidate()` on the frame. Check out [revalidate VS repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint)

Comment: For better help, show a small complete example program, not your entire program and not un-runnable snippets, but rather a [mcve]. Question though: why is focus necessary? Are you using a KeyListener? If so, change to Key Bindings.

Comment: Unrelated issues: draw in `paintComponent`, not `paint`. And don't change the state of your object (the `x` variable) from within a painting method since you do not have full control over when or if painting will be done. Change the state within the timer itself. Also better to swap views with a CardLayout then to manually do it as you're coding it.

Comment: revalidate(); was the answer to my question, I saw that there is a relative question that Vice Emigh linked to me, so I think this post is useless and I have to remove it, right?

Comment: We'll just mark the question a duplicate, and kudos to @VinceEmigh for his recommendations.