# What commands the "windowDeiconified" WindowListener is using once it is called?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, panel, frame

*Sorry for the Title! don't know how else to ask this question..*

I use the command `revalidate()`, and the window gets clear.

if I want to add `KeyListener` on window what should I put?

if the window gets `windowDeiconified` that event, the KeyListener works fine.

So my main question is what else codes need to (re-work) the keyListener without re-opening it?

What should I use indeed of `revalidate()` and not *re-opening* the window to get my keyListener work?

I tried to google it but I really don't know how to search t hat issue.. also haven't seen anyone talking about that... I don't know what I'm missing here.

Down below is the Code and the Classes that I'm using on.

Starting Class:

```
package MainPackage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Starting_Window {

    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Simple Game By Erick");
    public static GameFrameMenu menuG = new GameFrameMenu();
    public static PlayingClass game;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800/4*3);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(menuG);

    }

}
```

Menu Class:

```
package MainPackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GameFrameMenu extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static Timer menuTimer;

    public GameFrameMenu() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setLayout(null);

        color = new Color(rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255));

        menuTimer = new Timer(10,this);
        menuTimer.start();

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start Game!");
        btnStart.setBounds(285, 180, 200, 40);
        btnStart.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnStart.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        add(btnStart);

        JButton btnOptions = new JButton("Options!");
        btnOptions.setBounds(285, 240, 200, 40);
        btnOptions.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnOptions.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        add(btnOptions);

        JButton btnAboutUs = new JButton("About Us!");
        btnAboutUs.setBounds(285, 300, 200, 40);
        btnAboutUs.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnAboutUs.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        add(btnAboutUs);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit!");
        btnExit.setBounds(285, 360, 200, 40);
        btnExit.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnExit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        add(btnExit);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////

        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Starting_Window.game = new PlayingClass();
                menuTimer.stop();
                Starting_Window.menuG.removeAll();
                Starting_Window.menuG.repaint();
                Starting_Window.frame.repaint();
                Starting_Window.frame.add(Starting_Window.game);
                Starting_Window.game.setFocusable(true);
                Starting_Window.game.repaint();
                Starting_Window.frame.remove(Starting_Window.menuG);
                Starting_Window.frame.revalidate();

            }
        });

        btnOptions.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            }
        });

        btnAboutUs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            }
        });

        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });


    }

    Font HEADER = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 35);

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setFont(HEADER);
        g2d.drawString("The Simple Game Here By Erick ", 90, 145);


        setBackground(color);
        pushTimer();



        drawEffects(g2d);
    }

    public int limiterEffect = 0;

    public void drawEffects(Graphics2D g2d) {

        limiterEffect++;
        if(limiterEffect<15) {
            g2d.setColor(getRandomColor(color));
            g2d.fillOval(rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(1000), 25, 25);
            g2d.setColor(getRandomColor(color));
            g2d.fillOval(rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(1000), 25, 25);
            g2d.setColor(getRandomColor(color));
            g2d.fillOval(rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(1000), 25, 25);
            g2d.setColor(getRandomColor(color));
            g2d.fillOval(rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(1000), 25, 25);
            g2d.setColor(getRandomColor(color));
            g2d.fillOval(rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(1000), 25, 25);
            g2d.setColor(getRandomColor(color));
            g2d.fillOval(rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(1000), 25, 25);
            g2d.setColor(getRandomColor(color));
            g2d.fillOval(rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(1000), 25, 25);
            g2d.setColor(getRandomColor(color));
            g2d.fillOval(rand.nextInt(1000), rand.nextInt(1000), 25, 25);

        }
        if(limiterEffect==30) {
            limiterEffect = 0;
        }


    }

    static int counterTimer = 0, counterTimerDelay = 50;
    static int canDisplay = 0;

    public void pushTimer() {
        counterTimer++;
        if(counterTimer==counterTimerDelay) {
            color = getRandomColor(color);
            counterTimer = 0;
            counterTimerDelay = rand.nextInt(200)+50;
        }
    }

    public Color getRandomColor(Color c) {
        int R,G,B;
        R = rand.nextInt(255);
        G = rand.nextInt(255);
        B = rand.nextInt(255);
        c = new Color(R,G,B);
        return c;
    }

    static Random rand = new Random();
    static Color color;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        repaint();

    }




}
```

Playing Class that has been called from MenuClass:

```
package MainPackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class PlayingClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener  {

    Timer gameTimer;
    Player player;

    public PlayingClass() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(new Color(GameFrameMenu.rand.nextInt(255),GameFrameMenu.rand.nextInt(255),GameFrameMenu.rand.nextInt(255)));

        gameTimer = new Timer(10,this);
        gameTimer.start();

        player = new Player(200,200);
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapt(player));



    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        player.draw(g2d);


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        player.update();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Entity class:

```
package MainPackage;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Entity {
    int x, y;

    public Entity(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {

    }
}
```

Player class that extends Entity Class:

```
package MainPackage;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player extends Entity {

    int velY = 0, velX = 0;

    public Player(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    public void update() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {

        g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImg(), x, y, null);

    }

    public Image getPlayerImg() {
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("C:\\Java Pictures\\baseball pictures\\mini_player.png");
        return i.getImage();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Something happened");
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

and finally the KeyAdapt class the is (sync) with Player class:

```
    package MainPackage;

    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

    public class KeyAdapt extends KeyAdapter {

        Player p;

        public KeyAdapt(Player player) {
            p = player;
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            p.keyPressed(e);
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            p.keyReleased(e);
        }


}
```

So the issue here is, when i press the Start Button, The Screen Gets clear, i can see whatever happens in PlayingClass, but the KeyListener is not working. To make that work I have to minimize and deiconified the window in order to enable the KeyListener. So i hope i explain it better and you can help me.

Comment: In the first launch i thought i have done something wrong with keyListener, but then i realized that the problem is i had to minimize and get the window back to top again...

Comment: What exactly is the problem you’re having?  Is it that a KeyListener stops working after the user manipulates the window in some way?  Is it that you want your KeyListener to receive events when the window is iconified/minimized?

Comment: no, it doesn't work at all at begin, i have to re-open it to work propertly. I passed the a new Panel from another panel like i had asked here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099831/setting-focusable-window-on-jpanel-from-another-jpanel-by-frames-command-class[link]   and the keyListener is not working. after i re-open the window it works. i want to make keylistener works without re-open my window. in previous question on link above i asked how to clear the screen, now im asking how to enable keyListener without re-opening the window.

Comment: You need to provide all of the details of your circumstances in your question (not in comments), by editing your question.  First, show the code that *does* work.  Then explain the circumstances or events that cause it not to work.  Also, in your question, explain what “doesn’t work” means—does the KeyListener simply never get called?

Comment: okay, i will copy/paste my entire code. and explain what i want to do.

Comment: *"but the KeyListener is not working"* - Yeah, it does that, it's a well known and documented issue - the most reliable answer is - [use the Key Bindings API instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)