# Add a new component to a JPanel created in another class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jlabel

I have a `JFrame` with a grid of `JPanels` (using `Borderlayout`). Each `JPanel` holds a `JButton` (that expands to full size because is inside a `Borderlayout`). So I have something like a minesweeper.

Those buttons have a listener, with the constructor Listener(panel), so i can use the panel from the listener.

If I do `panel.removeAll();` in the listener then the button disappears, but the `JPanel` remains, so i get a free space.

I do `panel.setBackground(Color.pink);` and it works, but if i want to add a component, such another button or a `JLabel`, it doesn't work. It works in the same class but not apart, or in a method of the class.

Thank you. Hope you can understand!

Here it is my listener class:

```
public class ListenerCasillas implements ActionListener {

    JPanel panel;

    ListenerCasillas(JPanel panel){

    this.panel = panel;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        panel.removeAll();//works
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);//works
        panel.add(new JLabel("1"));//doesn't work
        panel.repaint();//works

    }

}
```

And here it is the class that creates the grid:

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
    Game(){
        super("MineSweeper 0.0");
        setLocation(300, 300);
        setResizable(false);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(mainclass.rows, mainclass.cols));

        Dimension d = new Dimension(30, 30);

        for(int i = 0; i < mainclass.rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < mainclass.cols; j++){
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                panel.setPreferredSize(d);

                add(panel);

                JButton boton = new JButton();

                boton.addActionListener(new ListenerCasillas(panel));
                panel.add(boton);
            }
        }

        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }
}
```

Full java project (if you want to test):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0WNwgY4eOjvNmNHM0E5U0FxVGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What happens if you move `panel.repaint();` to the end of `actionPerformed`?  It seems strange to tell it to repaint in the middle of modifying it

Comment: @phflack it was just for the removing of the button, i changed it but it's the same.

Comment: Makes sense, since adding a component should force a repaint.  What happens if you change `Dimension d = new Dimension(30, 30);` to something bigger?  300x300 should be enough space to render a label (for testing)

Comment: @phflack Nothing, very big green square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to call `revalidate()` in your `ListenerCasillas`s `actionPerformed()` method

```
public class ListenerCasillas implements ActionListener {
    JPanel panel;

    ListenerCasillas(JPanel panel){
        this.panel = panel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panel.removeAll();
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel.add(new JLabel("1"));
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
    }
}
```

For more information on `repaint()` and `revalidate()` check out [this brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1097544/4298200) on SO.