# One time only data display on the Jasper report in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

i am creating jasper report for view the student details. i have a textfield if the enter correct student id relavent student details display on the jsper report below. i called the jsper report inside the jpanel.
[image]

if i enter first time student id  3 it displayed result success then if i enter the second time student id 4 the same result shown. i don't know why.

```
  HashMap a = new HashMap();
        a.put("id", txtno.getText());

        try {

        JasperDesign jdesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\kobinath\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication138\\src\\report1.jrxml");
        JasperReport jreport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jdesign);        
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, a, con);
         //  JasperViewer.viewReport(jprint);
         JRViewer vw=new JRViewer(jprint); 
         jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         jPanel1.repaint();

         jPanel1.add(vw);
         jPanel1.revalidate();



        } catch (JRException ex) {

        }
```

Comment: When you debug the code, what values are being held in `a` after `a.put("id", txtno.getText());`?

Comment: sir i tested through the jsperviewer successfullly working but if i call this inside jpanel had problem for enter next id. i think refresh the report

Comment: ("id", txtno.getText())   student id 3 displayed on  txtno.getText() success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `revalidate()` alone isn't enough to refresh the panel. You may reference to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1097544/6941952) to make sure that `repaint()` is better to be called.
I hope this helps you solve your problem.

P.S. You can swap the two lines before the last line.

Comment: i tried     repaint(); revalidate(); not working for me

Comment: You may call ```revalidate()``` first. If the problem is still there, then it's advisable to make ```jPanel1``` a new instance of its class.