# How to make a JButton that will create other buttons in java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a user system to hold multiple details of multiple users, so I would like to create a button that would be able to create another button. When the second button is pressed a form will open for the user to fill. I have already created the form for the user to fill but I cannot manage to make the button to create more buttons to work. I have coded this but it does not show the button on the `JPanel`.

I have created the following code:

```
private void mainButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
    JButton b=new JButton("Click Here"); 
    b.setBounds(50,100,95,30);  
    jPanel3.add(b); 
    b.setVisible(true); 
}
```

I want to know what is the correct code to write in the events / mouseClick of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add or remove components from a `JPanel`, you need to make that `JPanel` redraw itself. Just adding or removing a component does not make this happen. Hence, after adding or removing a component from a `JPanel`, you need to call method `revalidate` followed by a call to `repaint`.

Refer to [Java Swing revalidate() vs repaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint)

Also note that the following line of your code is not required since the `visible` property is true by default.

```java
b.setVisible(true);
```

Also, it is recommended to use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) which means you don't need to call method `setBounds` as you have in this line of your code.

```java
b.setBounds(50,100,95,30);
```

### EDIT

As requested, a sample application. Clicking on the `Add` button will add another button. Note that the [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for the `Add` button is implemented as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonAd {
    private static final String  ADD = "Add";

    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPanel  buttonsPanel;

    private void addButton(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Added");
        buttonsPanel.add(button);
        buttonsPanel.revalidate();
        buttonsPanel.repaint();
    }

    private JPanel createAddButton() {
        JPanel addButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton addButton = new JButton(ADD);
        addButton.addActionListener(this::addButton);
        addButtonPanel.add(addButton);
        return addButtonPanel;
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Add Buttons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createAddButton(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        buttonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 350));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new ButtonAd().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much thanks man