# Label is not added in Jframe in an Externam function

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

i have created a button which is supposed to add "label" to my frame but it just doesn't work it prints "starting..." but not adds the "label" Here's my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class NameHere extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton button = new JButton("Start");
JLabel label = new JLabel("Starting the App");
NameHere() {

    button.setBounds(212,235,75,30);
    button.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);
    label.setBounds(250,50,250,20);
    this.setSize(500,500);
    this.setTitle("Platformer");
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.add(button);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==button){
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        NameHere.this.add(label);//Here it should add the label to the frame
    }
}
}
```

in this code in the function actionPerformed it should add the label but it didn't work but when I try to add it in my Namehere function it works.

Comment: `NameHere.this.repaint();` after adding the label

Comment: thx bro it worked the other way but i'll keep this in mind.:)

Answer (score 1):

From the [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/troubleshoot/swing.html#GUID-391FD503-7B22-4A46-8446-8917B33F5BAC):

> **Add or Remove Components**
>
> When you add or remove components, you must
> manually invoke repaint or revalidate Swing and AWT.

Best invoke both, see [Java Swing revalidate() vs repaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint).

Now the code as [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class NameHere extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton button = new JButton("Start");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Starting the App");
    NameHere() {
        button.setBounds(212,235,75,30);
        button.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);
        label.setBounds(250,50,250,20);
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setTitle("Platformer");
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(button);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==button){
            System.out.println("Starting...");
            NameHere.this.add(label);//Here it should add the label to the frame
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NameHere();
            }
        });
    }
}
```